# Confusion about properties of orthogonal eigenvectors

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, orthogonality

I'm trying to show that for any matrix $A$ $\in$ $\mathbb R$<sup>m×n</sup>, if $v$<sub>1</sub> and $v$<sub>2</sub> are orthogonal eigenvectors of $A^TA$ then Av<sub>1</sub> and Av<sub>2</sub> are orthogonal.

I know that $A^TA$ is symmetric which means its eigenvectors are orthogonal 
and I have found that if $v$ is an eigenvector of $A^TA$ with eigenvalue $\lambda \neq 0$, then $Av$ is an eigenvector of $AA^T$. I feel that these properties are important in proving the above but I am unsure how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\langle Av_1 , Av_2 \rangle =\langle A^{T}Av_1 , v_2 \rangle =\lambda_1 \langle v_1, v_2 \rangle=0$ where $\lambda_1$ is the eigen value corresponding to $v_1$.

Comment: Could you please explain the first step?

Comment: @Umber For any real matrix $B$ and vectors $x,y$ we have $\langle x , By \rangle =\langle B^{T}x  , y \rangle$.